# Copy multiple columns (in different order) from a source workbook to a destination workbook and paste it below the last non empty row

Tags: excel, vba

I have two different work books named `Input.xlsb` (Source data) and Lapsed Pipeline.xlsm (destination workbook). I have searched the codes here and found one which helped me partially but the issue with this code is the data of one column gets pasted below the other . Eg:Column D gets pasted correctly in last non empty cell, but data in column gets pasted in the last row after data in column and like wise for every columns, i want all the data from the source data to be pasted after the last non empty row at once. below is code i have reedited for my purpose.

Example:

[image]

```
Sub CopyCoverage()

Dim x As Worksheet, y As Worksheet, LastRow&

Set x = Workbooks("Input.xlsb").Worksheets("Opportunity")
Set y = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lapsed Opps")

LastRow = x.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

x.Range("G2:G" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)     
x.Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)    
x.Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)    
x.Range("Y2:Y" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)    
x.Range("Z2:Z" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)    
x.Range("AJ2:AJ" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)    
x.Range("AK2:AK" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)    
x.Range("AL2:AL" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)    
x.Range("AM2:AM" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)     
x.Range("EC2:EC" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)     
x.Range("EG2:EG" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)     

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You question is quite ambiguous, Column D gets pasted correctly but what you want is for source data to be pasted after the last non empty row at once? What is the issue? Could you include an image of what is happening and your desired result?

Comment: I have two different work books named Input.xlsb (Source data) and Lapsed Pipeline.xlsm (destination workbook). I have searched the codes here and found one which helped me partially but the issue with this code is the data of one column gets pasted below the other . Eg:Column D gets pasted correctly in last non empty cell, but data in column M gets pasted in the last row after data in column D and like wise for every columns, i want all the data from the source data to be pasted after the last non empty row at once. below is code i have reedited for my purpose.

Comment: repeating what was already ambiguous, is not giving us a better understanding, please could you include in your question images of actual result and desired result?

Comment: @VenusJain Just attach pictures with dummy data if it is confidential.

Comment: Hello Sorry if my comments and questions are not clear, am new to the site and just now uploaded the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following, if I understood correctly:

```
Sub CopyCoverage()

Dim x As Worksheet, y As Worksheet, LastRow&, yLastRow&

Set x = Workbooks("Input.xlsb").Worksheets("Opportunity")
Set y = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lapsed Opps")

LastRow = x.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
yLastRow = y.Cells(y.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

x.Range("G2:G" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(yLastRow, "D").End(xlUp)
x.Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(yLastRow, "M").End(xlUp)
x.Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(yLastRow, "A").End(xlUp)
x.Range("Y2:Y" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(yLastRow, "C").End(xlUp)
x.Range("Z2:Z" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(yLastRow, "B").End(xlUp)
x.Range("AJ2:AJ" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(yLastRow, "G").End(xlUp)
x.Range("AK2:AK" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(yLastRow, "H").End(xlUp)
x.Range("AL2:AL" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(yLastRow, "I").End(xlUp)
x.Range("AM2:AM" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(yLastRow, "J").End(xlUp)
x.Range("EC2:EC" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(yLastRow, "F").End(xlUp)
x.Range("EG2:EG" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(yLastRow, "E").End(xlUp)

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Rows.Count` and `End(xlUp)`, store the bottom row of the `UsedRange` in a variable before you start copying:

```
Dim PasteRow AS Long
PasteRow = y.UsedRange.Rows(y.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1
x.Range("G2:G" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(PasteRow, 4)  'Do not change PasteRow
x.Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(PasteRow, 13)  'et cetera
```

**{EDIT}** Longer code, removes the requirement for UsedRange, still accepts that some columns may have blank cells:

```
'This replaces your Copy block - everything before stays as you wrote it
Dim PasteRow As Long, iCheckCol AS Integer
PasteRow = 0
For iCheckCol = 1 to 10 'Check columns A - J
    If y.Cells(y.Rows.Count, iCheckCol).End(xlUp).Row > PasteRow Then
        PasteRow = y.Cells(y.Rows.Count, iCheckCol).End(xlUp).Row 'Find lowest bottom of rows
    End If
Next iCheckCol
PasteRow = PasteRow+1 'Go down from the Bottom Row
x.Range("G2:G" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(PasteRow, 4)  'Do not change PasteRow
x.Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(PasteRow, 13)  'et cetera
'Add a line for every column that you want to copy
```

Comment: If OP has more than one table on a worksheet, using `.UsedRange` will be highly inaccurate, not to mention that `.UsedRange` includes blank cells with changed format or cells with their content deleted in current session.

Comment: Hello, Am new to VBA, it would be highly helpful if you paste the entire code

Comment: The code I wrote just replaces your Copy block - i.e. everything from `x.Range("G2:G" & LastRow).Copy` to `y.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` The rest of your code is fine.  All it does is eliminate cases where you have empty cells at the bottom of a column that `End(xlUp)` will skip through

Comment: Hello, I will try using this code as well and let you know if i encountered any issues